# reading csv files with specific name in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have some csv files with name pattern below

IU_2022-09-01T09_43_56_**0100**-0018-0000-0002

Bold part of the name is important and i want to create different data frames if that changes  but i am not able to read csv files by specifying something in the middle of the name.
i want to read only  those csv files which has 0100 in their names.
i used glob method

```
ls_data = list()
```

for idx, f in glob.glob('[0100]*.csv'):

df_temp = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=';')

df_temp["layer_number"] = idx

ls_data.append(df_temp)

print (idx)

df_L = pd.concat(ls_data, axis=0)

`

but i am getting empty data

Comment: To me, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: `for filename in os.listdir(your_folder): if 'some_pattern' in filename: pd.read_csv(f'{your_folder}/{filename})`? Of course, with proper indentation.

Comment: I have a specific pattern in my file name (IU_date_time_pnumber_weldid_layernumber_job_program.
i want to read csv files based on (weld id). i want all csv files having same weld id in their names.

Comment: use the `glob` module or the `pathlib.Path.glob` method

Comment: ls_data = list()
# for filename in glob.glob('/path/to/csvfiles/*.csv'):
for idx, f in glob.glob('[0100]*.csv'):
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=';')
    df_temp["layer_number"] = idx
    # df = pd.concat([df, df_temp], axis=0)
    ls_data.append(df_temp)
    print (idx)
df_L = pd.concat(ls_data, axis=0)
but i am getting empty data frames

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a large csv file with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`pathlib`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) :

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

ls_data = []

csv_directory = r'/path/to/csvfiles/'

for idx, filename in enumerate(Path(csv_directory).glob('*_0100-*.csv')):
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';')
    df_temp.insert(0, 'layer_number', idx)
    ls_data.append(df_temp) 

df = pd.concat(ls_data, axis=0)
```

Comment: can i use idx for giving a number to every csv file i read? i tried but its not working

Comment: Can you be more specific, please ? What happened exactly ? You got an error ?

Comment: it works perfectly, he saw the edit later