# Read in call CSV files with the same naming convention and insert new two new columns from splitting filename

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, google-colaboratory

I used this solution to read in all CSV files from a Google Drive into a data frame in a Colab notebook using this solution ([reading csv file with specific name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73806383/21407177)). Each file has the same naming convention and I want to split the file name into two new columns and append those to the dataframe.

The file name are structured like this: Platform_Company.csv (example Instagram_Microsoft.csv) and I want the columns to be appended at the beginning of the dataframe.

| platform | company | employee id | employee email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instagram | Microsoft | person 1 | humanperson@microsoft.com |

So far, I've used this to read in the files. I'm not sure what the layer number is or whether I need it.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

ls_data = []

csv_directory = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/'

for idx, filename in enumerate(Path(csv_directory).glob('*Instagram_*.csv')):
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df_temp.insert(0, 'layer_number', idx)
    ls_data.append(df_temp) 

df = pd.concat(ls_data, axis=0)
```

I tried incorporating the following script ([Read multiple csv files and Add filename as new column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42756959/21407177)), but it isn't working and I'm not sure how to add it into the current version.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r'\OUTPUT'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='|') for f in all_files)
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
concatenated_df['filename'] =(all_files[f] for f in all_files)
```

Thanks for any guidance and/or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(Platform, Company)` as the key of a dict then use `pd.concat` to get the expected output:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

csv_directory = pathlib.Path('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/')

data = {}
for filename in csv_directory.glob('*Instagram_*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    platform, company = filename.stem.split('_')
    data[platform, company] = df

df = (pd.concat(data, axis=0).droplevel(-1)
        .rename_axis(['platform', 'company']).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    platform    company employee id             employee email
0  Instagram  Microsoft    person 1  humanperson@microsoft.com
1  Instagram   Facebook    person 2   humanperson@facebook.com
2  Instagram   Facebook    person 3   humanperson@facebook.com
```

Input files

```
# Instagram_Microsoft.csv
employee id,employee email
person 1,humanperson@microsoft.com

# Instagram_Facebook.csv
employee id,employee email
person 2,humanperson@facebook.com
person 3,humanperson@facebook.com
```

Comment: I want to try just grabbing the text before the underscore and tried removing company, but keep getting errors. It doesn't seem to find all of the files. How can I return just the part of the filename before the underscore to the list?  I tried this - 
s.str.rsplit("/", n=1, expand=True) - but got this error AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I also tried modifying it like this: https://pastebin.com/QeLGiyV3 and got this error: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'split'